# form refresh on 'NEXT' button click instead of going into next step

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 1 matrimony website (ASP.NET, C#). Registration form in the website is divided into 5 steps (screenshot below).

[image]

Mostly its running okay but **My main problem sometimes the form refresh on 'NEXT' button click instead of going into next step. and sometimes it auto redirect to index page of the website.**

I just don't know why it's happening. I have checked the coding 100 times and I don't find any problem with the coding. Any help will be appreciated.

Mostly this happens in random steps not fixed in which step it redirect,
But I am posting a button_click event of NEXT' button reg step 2 page:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_FreeUserProfile where UserId='" + Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString() + "'", con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.HasRows == true)
{
    ImageButton46.Enabled = false;
    string userid = Request.QueryString["userid"];

    DateTime last_activity = System.DateTime.Now;
    int heightf = Convert.ToInt16(DropDownList30.SelectedItem.Value);
    string str1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cn1 = new SqlConnection(str1);
    string query1 = "update tbl_FreeUserProfile set Height='" + DropDownList30.SelectedItem.Text + "',Weight='" + DropDownList31.SelectedItem.Text + "',BloodGroup='" + DropDownList32.SelectedItem.Text + "',PhysicalStatus='" + RadioButtonList7.SelectedItem.Text + "',heightf='" + heightf + "' where UserId='" + userid + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, cn1);

    cn1.Open();
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn1.Close();
    Response.Redirect("~/Registration-Details-Step-3.aspx?username=" + Request.QueryString["username"].ToString() + "&userid=" + userid);
}
```

Comment: We can't help you unless we can see the code that controls the "next" behaviour. Do you have an onclick event attached to the next button? Why don't you start by posting that?

Comment: You're gonna need to show us some code.  You've basically told us your app doesn't do what you want, and you're asking us to guess why.

Comment: question updated. Thanks

Comment: What would happen if no rows found for given user? Refresh?

Comment: i don't think so as at the step when registering username and password, i insert userId also and then redirect to 1st step of the profile registration process.

Answer (score 0):

Please try use this code

```
if(!isPostBack)
{
//Your code
}
```

this code allow you to

Comment: will it stop the page to auto redirect to index or refresh?

Answer (score 0):

And Why you not try Panels in your design page and  so in last panel you have to fire submit event this will not refresh your page in  starting step only final step page is load.

Answer (score -1):

hi i have 1 query regards your form if any scenario like when you fill first step and going to second step if power is off now and when next time you come in registration form is there any way we have to see already fill step in my first step and i do not need to fill first step which is filled already as before ?.